# QGIS ArcGIS FeatureServer not working

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to open on QGIS 2.18/3.4.1 the follow layer:

```
https://services2.arcgis.com/1GTOs4RWV6SKu0wr/ArcGIS/rest/services/Comunidades/FeatureServer/0
```

Both layer>add layer> mapsource or featureserver

How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.4.1:

Go To Layer->Add Layer->ArcGIS-Feature-Server.

Add a New Connection, enter a name and the following URL:
  https://services2.arcgis.com/1GTOs4RWV6SKu0wr/ArcGIS/rest/services/Comunidades/FeatureServer

then click "add".